# how to getting numbers from calculator text area(without operators)?

Tags: java, variables, operators, calculator

in my previous question, i got no useful answer, i hope i get something :)

here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class Calculator extends JFrame
{
  public Calculator()
{
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("Calculator");
    jf.setLocation(500,200);
    jf.setSize(600,400);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    /*=======================Add panel==============================
    ================================================================*/
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(null);
    jp.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    jf.add(jp);

    /*========================Add Textarea========================
    ================================================================*/

    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea("");
    jta.setBounds(100,25,290,50);
    jp.add(jta);

    /*========================Creating Font========================
    ===============================================================*/

    Font labels = new Font("Lucida Console",Font.PLAIN, 20);
    Font nums = new Font("Lucida Console",Font.PLAIN, 9);

    /*========================Add Labels============================
    ================================================================*/

    /*  for H align: ,SwingConstants.CENTER */
    JLabel jlbl = new JLabel("=");
    jlbl.setFont(labels);   //  MAKING FONT BIGGER
    jlbl.setBounds(400,30,50,40);
    jp.add(jlbl);


    JLabel jlbl_result = new JLabel();
    String temp = jta.getText();
    jlbl_result.setText(temp);

    /*=========================Adding button============================
    ====================================================================*/

    JButton jbtn1 = new JButton("1");
    jbtn1.setBounds(120,100,50,40);
    jbtn1.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn1);

    JButton jbtn2 = new JButton("2");
    jbtn2.setBounds(180,100,50,40);
    jbtn2.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn2);

    JButton jbtn3 = new JButton("3");
    jbtn3.setBounds(240,100,50,40);
    jbtn3.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn3);

    JButton jbtn4 = new JButton("4");
    jbtn4.setBounds(120,155,50,40);
    jbtn4.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn4);

    JButton jbtn5 = new JButton("5");
    jbtn5.setBounds(180,155,50,40);
    jbtn5.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn5);

    JButton jbtn6 = new JButton("6");
    jbtn6.setBounds(240,155,50,40);
    jbtn6.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn6);

    JButton jbtn7 = new JButton("7");
    jbtn7.setBounds(120,210,50,40);
    jbtn7.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn7);

    JButton jbtn8 = new JButton("8");
    jbtn8.setBounds(180,210,50,40);
    jbtn8.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn8);

    JButton jbtn9 = new JButton("9");
    jbtn9.setBounds(240,210,50,40);
    jbtn9.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn9);

    JButton jbtn0 = new JButton("0");
    jbtn0.setBounds(180,265,50,40);
    jbtn0.setBackground(Color.green);
    jp.add(jbtn0);

    JButton jbtn_sum = new JButton("+");
    jbtn_sum.setBounds(380,100,40,40);
    jbtn_sum.setFont(nums);
    jbtn_sum.setBackground(Color.gray);
    jp.add(jbtn_sum);

    JButton jbtn_sub = new JButton("-");
    jbtn_sub.setBounds(380,100,40,40);
    jbtn_sub.setFont(nums);
    jbtn_sub.setBackground(Color.gray);
    jp.add(jbtn_sub);

    JButton jbtn_equal = new JButton("-");
    jbtn_equal.setBounds(380,155,40,40);
    jbtn_equal.setFont(nums);
    jp.add(jbtn_equal);


    jf.setVisible(true);

            jbtn1.addActionListener(e->jta.append("1"));
            jbtn2.addActionListener(e->jta.append("2"));
            jbtn3.addActionListener(e->jta.append("3"));
            jbtn4.addActionListener(e->jta.append("4"));
            jbtn5.addActionListener(e->jta.append("5"));
            jbtn6.addActionListener(e->jta.append("6"));
            jbtn7.addActionListener(e->jta.append("7"));
            jbtn8.addActionListener(e->jta.append("8"));
            jbtn9.addActionListener(e->jta.append("9"));
            jbtn0.addActionListener(e->jta.append("0"));
            jbtn_equal.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt2)
                {

                }
            });
            //jbtn_sub.addActionListener(e->jta.append("-"));
            jbtn_sum.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {

                }
            });
}
public static void main(String...ser)
{
    new Calculator();
}
}
```

i know! there is a lot of code, i want to put number that i entered to JTextArea inside variable, how to get numbers(just numbers without operators )
and assign it to variable?

and... how many variable is required to do it?(in case if i have more than 5 variable)

and a lot of questions..., i cant write it down here

thank you for help(forgive me of my bad grammar)

Comment: "and a lot of questions..., i cant write it down here": If you want those questions answered, you'll need to write them down.

Answer (score 0):

You download the text from JTextArea and save it to the new String. If you download only numbers, just use the `parseInt ()` function to convert String to int.
If you enter an action with operators eg 2 + 2 then you can use patterns to capture numbers, you can use the `split ()` function to separate 2 numbers in the String with some sign, the possibilities are many;)

If this is not what you had in mind, compose the question and I will try to help.

Comment: I think i got it! But how to remove operators from entered formula? and if you can tell me, How to set the mathematics rules? for .e.g->('*' is work before '+' or  '-')? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the text from the JTextArea and then split it by non-number characters into an array of Strings, like this:

```
String[] numbers = jta.getText().split("\\D+");
```

For example, if you used this regex to split the string "1+23-5" you would get this array: {"1","23","5"}.

If you want to store the numbers as ints, use a for-each loop to copy the String array into an int array:

```
int[] ints = new int[numbers.length]
for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
}
```

Then, instead of putting each number in a separate variable, just keep them in the array and access them by index when needed.

Comment: thank you ! it worked!!  still i have to think how to work with the numbers  , another question please! is this codes work when i have a different operators? ( -,/,*,...)

Comment: Yes, it will work. The regex splits the string on any character that is not a number.

Comment: @mhamadarsalan If this answer was helpful to you, please consider choosing it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry i have skipped that project for a while, Thanks but i noticed something! First It's not (for-each) loop, it's a regular (for) loop i guess, and Second thing your RegEx is ignore the numbers! It takes everything without numbers and it makes no scene for working with, i used [This Website](http://regex101.com) it helps me a little bit, BTW thank you for answer

Comment: You're welcome. Did your question get answered eventually? If not, then you should probably ask a new question. I don't really understand what you mean by ignore the numbers, or about the loop. But I hope you were able to figure it out.